# MySQL migrate from one DB to another

Tags: mysql, database

This is what I have:

```
1 MySQL db with 2 schemas

 - schema 1
 - schema 2
```

They both have a table called files,

```
 with 3 fields

 - Name
 - Play
 - Date
```

Both schemas have the name `filed populated`, and `schema 1 has Play and Date populated`..

I want to import all records or Play and Date into schema 2 where the Name is the same as schema 1..

so

```
Schema 1

 - Name = A
 - Play = 1
 - Date = 25/06/17

Schema 2

 - Name = A
 - Play =
 - Date =
```

I want Play and Date inserted to schema 2 where Name matches in the two databases..

I have this query -

```
INSERT INTO schema2.test (Play, Date) 
SELECT Play, Date FROM schema1.test;
```

I can't work out the where clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to update one table from the other:

```
update schema2.files f2 join
       schema1.files f1
       on f2.name = f1.name
    set f2.play = f1.play,
        f2.date = f1.date;
```

For performance, you will want an index on `schema1.files(name)` . . . or better yet, `schema1.files(name, play, date)`.

This assumes that `name` is unique in the two tables -- identifying each row.  If this is not true, I would suggest a very different approach.  Store the names in a separate table, then truncate `schema2.files` and insert the new records in:

```
create table schema2.temp_names as
    select distinct name
    from schema2.files;

truncate table schema2.files;

insert into schema2.files(name, play, date)
    select f1.name, f1.play, f1.date
    from schema1.files f1
    where f1.name in (select n.name from schema2.temp_names n);

drop table schema2.temp_names;  -- if you want
```

Actually, this approach might have better performance in general, if your tables are large.

Comment: same as mine one.

Comment: When I run the first query, that is working, it keeps timing out with "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE 
schema2.test T2
INNER JOIN schema1.test T1 ON T1.Name=T2.Name
Set T2.Play=T1.Play,T2.Date=T1.Date
```

Here you don't need to insert record in schema 2 as there is already record with Name column.

So instead of insert you have to update that record with specific record of `Schema1`

Just try above code.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update

```
update database2.files t_dest
inner join database1.files t_orig on t.dest.name = t_orig.name
set t_dest.play  = t_orig.play,
    t_dest.date = t_orig.date
```

and an insert select

```
insert into database2.files ( Name, Play, Date)
select  Name, Play, Date
from database1.files 
inner join database2.files 
where database1.name <>  database2.name
```

Comment: It make no sense that this would be the accepted answer.  The second query, for instance, is rather non-sensical.